# Did CUDA programming change from C to C++?

Tags: cuda

Before I dive too deep into CUDA programming I need to orient myself.  The NVIDIA CUDA programming guides made a distinct change from referring to "CUDA C" to "CUDA C++" between versions 10.1 and 10.2.  Since this was a minor version change, I suspect it is just semantics.  I compared sample code from pre-10.1 and post-10.2 and found no difference...though that doesn't mean there is no difference.  Was there a more subtle programming paradigm shift between these versions?

Here's my suspicion: CUDA has always been an extension of C++, not C, but everyone has referred to it as CUDA C because the we don't take advantage of the OOP offered by C++ when writing CUDA code.  Is that a fair assessment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your assessment is reasonable conjecture.  People are sometimes imprecise in their references to C and C++, and so CUDA probably hasn't been very rigorous here either.  There is some history though that suggests to me this is not purely hand-waving.

CUDA started out as largely a C-style realization, but over time added C++ style features.  Certainly by CUDA 4.0 (circa 2010) if not before, there were plenty of C++ style features.

Lately, CUDA drops the reference to C but [claims compliance](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#c-cplusplus-language-support) to a particular C++ ISO standard, subject to various enumerated restrictions and limitations.

The CUDA compiler, `nvcc`, behaves by default like a C++ style compiler (so, for example, using C++ style mangling), and will by default invoke the host-code C++ compiler (e.g. `g++`) not the host code C compiler (e.g. `gcc`) when passing off host code to be compiled.

As you point out, a programmer can use the C++ language syntactically in a very similar way to C usage (e.g. without the use of classes, to pick one example).  This is also true for CUDA C++.

It's not possible to build Rome in a day, and so CUDA development has proceeded in various areas at various rates.  For example, one [stated limitation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#standard-library) of CUDA is that elements of the standard library (`std::`) are not necessarily supported in device code.  However various CUDA developers are working to gradually fill in this gap with the [libcu++](https://nvidia.github.io/libcudacxx/) evolution.

Comment: That's helpful.  I have experience in C, not C++.  Does C++ specific syntax get brought into CUDA at all?  I guess the usual C --> C++ incompatibilities need to be avoided, right?

Comment: C++ specific syntax certainly gets brought into CUDA.  I don't really understand the question.  CUDA is much closer to C++ than it is to C, for the reasons I stated in my answer.  Also, as I stated in my answer, just like with C++, you can write CUDA code that appears to be purely C code, and it will work fine (just like you would expect it to work fine in C++).  It probably would be best if you thought of CUDA as C++, e.g. like using `g++`, and anything you would do as a C programmer to work in that setting (say, with `g++`) you probably would also do in CUDA C++.

Comment: Sorry, I'm just thinking of potential problems where C codes won't compile in C++ compiler.  Maybe I'm wrong, but I think memory allocation is done differently in C++, there are reserved words in C++ that should be avoided in C...that type of thing.

Comment: For C-style dynamic memory allocation, you can use `malloc` in C++ simply by including `<cstdlib>`.  You can use `malloc` in CUDA C++ also.   You should cast the returned pointer in both C++ and CUDA C++, contrary to what you should do in C.  `new` is a reserved word in C++ (but not C, I don't think), I wouldn't use that casually in my code (e.g. as a variable name).  None of this is specific to CUDA C++, it is true for C++ also.  So you should probably assume that general compatibility issues for using C code in C++ also apply to CUDA.

Comment: The initial release of CUDA was completely based on C, both in terms of interfaces and the toolchain. After the toolchain was switched to the Open64 infrastructure, a transition to limited C++ support was initiated, with templates being one of the first available C++ features. This started with CUDA 3.x in early 2008, if I recall correctly.